# First differencing with multiple time period in R / R studio

Tags: r

Hello everyone I am struggling with this exercise:
i have a dependent variable **y**, six dummy for the years from 1993 to 1998 and 3 other independent variable (**x1**,**x2**,**x3**). 
The question is to use first differencing to estimate a model that include an intercept and the dummy for the years 1994 to 1998. How I can do this in R?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: In R you have the `diff()` function, and you can specify the number of lag periods. For instance, if you have monthly data, the first difference for `x1` would be `diff(data$x1, 12)`

Comment: But what if for example I have a vector with 50 observations and the difference that I want to compute is the second object minus the first object, the fourth minus the third, the sixth minus the fifth and so on.. Obtaining in this way a new vector of 25 observations. In other words I don't want also the difference between the third and the second term.

Comment: I’d recommend asking that as a new question with sample data